# $(window).mouseup handler in a Chrome extension is breaking Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, events, google-chrome, event-bubbling

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that monitors mouse events. For some reason the following javascript code in the extension's [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) is causing embedded Flash content to break:

```
$(window).mouseup(function() {
    // do benign stuff
});
```

If you mousedown inside a Flash element, it never registers the mouseup and it appears as though you're still holding your mouse button down even though you've let go. At first I thought it was some kind of event bubbling issue, that this method was swallowing the event, so I tried returning true (and false for that matter) but it didn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, no response from the peanut gallery after a few days, but I figured it out on my lonesome:

```
// Bad
$(window).mouseup(function() { ... });

// Good
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) { ... });
```

Comment: is $(window) using the jQuery function or a different $ function? I'm having a similar problem and want to know if jQuery may be invoved.